# Records displaying repeatedly

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 1 query to fetch records from three table with help of inner joins.

```
table name

tbl_emp as emp
tbl_sal as sal
tbl_address as addr

fields from 3 tables

Schema:

tbl_emp - empid,name,comp_id
tbl_sal - empid - emp_type
tbl_address - emp_type
```

Query

```
SELECT emp.empid, emp.name, sal.salary, addr.address 
from tbl_emp as emp 
INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal 
  ON emp.empid = sal.empid 
INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr 
  ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type 
where comp_id = '114';
```

Result shows:

```
1 abc 1000 test
1 abc 1000 test
1 abc 1000 test
1 abc 1000 test
1 abc 1000 test
2 xyz 2500 main
2 xyz 2500 main
2 xyz 2500 main
2 xyz 2500 main
2 xyz 2500 main
```

I want result like:

```
1 abc 1000 test
2 xyz 2500 main
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Post the full ddl for the tables, it appears some fields are left out.  Also some sample data would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  emp.empid,
        emp.name,
        sal.salary,
        addr.address 
FROM tbl_emp as emp 
INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal 
    ON emp.empid = sal.empid 
INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr 
    ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type 
WHERE comp_id = '114'  
GROUP BY empid;
```

Comment: I would suggest editing this so it is reasonably easy to read. Instead of having one massive line.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample data, you should be able to use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.empid, 
  emp.name,
  sal.salary,
  addr.address 
from tbl_emp as emp 
INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal 
  ON emp.empid = sal.empid 
INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr 
  ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type 
where comp_id = '114';
```

`DISTINCT` is applied across all columns of data and will remove any duplicates.  Your limited sample will allow this to be applied.

You can also use `GROUP BY` to get the result.  My suggestion if you apply the `GROUP BY` would be to apply it to every item in your `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT emp.empid, 
  emp.name,
  sal.salary,
  addr.address 
from tbl_emp as emp 
INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal 
  ON emp.empid = sal.empid 
INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr 
  ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type 
where comp_id = '114'
GROUP BY emp.empid, emp.name, sal.salary, addr.address;
```

MySQL uses an extension to `GROUP BY` which allows items in a select list to be nonaggregated and not included in the `GROUP BY` clause.  This however can lead to unexpected results because MySQL can choose the values that are returned. (See [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Answer (score 1):

Use group by:

```
SELECT emp.empid,emp.name,sal.salary,addr.address from tbl_emp as emp INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal ON emp.empid = sal.empid INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type where comp_id = '114'
group by emp.empid,emp.name,sal.salary,addr.address
```

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT Keyword will do what you want, it will make sure duplicates are filtered out

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.empid,emp.name,sal.salary,addr.address from tbl_emp as emp INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal ON emp.empid = sal.empid INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type where comp_id = '114';
```

If you are getting duplicates though, you may want to make sure your query actually does what you think it does, otherwise you might have problems using DISTINCT, if there are genuine duplicates in your result set (rather than ones created by your query).

Answer (score 0):

try `group by` `emp.empid`

```
SELECT emp.empid,emp.name,sal.salary,addr.address from tbl_emp as emp INNER JOIN tbl_sal as sal ON emp.empid = sal.empid INNER JOIN tbl_address as addr ON addr.emp_type = sal.emp_type where comp_id = '114'  group by emp.empid ;
```